# DHClient stops working after resize2fs run

Tags: dns, dhcp, ipv6, ipv4

I had a weird issue with my hard drive where the filesystem wasn't occupying the entire partition. After rebooting a couple of times and running resize2fs I fixed this issue, however since doing so I can no longer establish a connection.

I am using DHClient to manage my DNS, but on initialisation it now runs `DHCPDISCOVER` repeatedly until it fails and returns `No DHCPOFFERS`. Then it prints `No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.` The DHCPCD service gives the respone `eno1: no IPv6 Routers available`. I'm at a loss here.

EDIT:
I'm not totally aware of the network configuration. I'm working off a university network in a data centre. The OS is Archlinux and I am assuming we are using Cisco routers. I have very little knowledge about networks, so please let me know specifically any information that may be needed.

dhcpcd.conf

```
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
#clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
# Some non-RFC compliant DHCP servers do not reply with this set.
# In this case, comment out duid and enable clientid above.
duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# Most distributions have NTP support.
#option ntp_servers

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate SLAAC address using the Hardware Address of the interface
#slaac hwaddr
# OR generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses based from the DUID
slaac private
noipv4ll
```

Comment: Some info about your operating system, routers, network architecture etc. will help.

Comment: Please show `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file.

Comment: I've added some info and config, let me know if more is needed.

Comment: I tried booting a usb install of Ubuntu and it also refuses to connect to the network. Is it an issue of the network card itself or perhaps the network?

Comment: How are you connected to that network? Wifi? Wired? If you use wired connection, could you connect your PC/laptop to another port (even on same switch or on an other)
Some switches (for security reasons) disable port when you change the connected device.

Comment: @deadcandidate it is wired and I have tried this

Comment: How much free space do you have on a partition (likely /) which holds dhclient lease database? Is it by any chance full?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much back and forth with the service team, it turned out that after the restart my IP was reassigned. Now fixed